# Создать динамический маршрут Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

на данный момент есть такой маршрут 
`category/{cid}-{clink}/` 
Получается, что передается только одна категория. А нужно чтобы категории перечислялись `category/{cid}-{clink}/{cid}-{clink}/{cid}-{clink}/` в зависимости от того, на каком уровне в древе категорий (хлебные крошки в URL).

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать маску

```
Route::get('category/{clink}', 'CategoryController@get')->where('clink', '.*');
```

Comment: Это да, только что на такое наткнулся, но если после категорий указать еще одну переменную, то все ломается)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев так, а что мешает объединить в одну, а внутри контроллера уже разбивать?

Comment: да ничего не мешает, просто думал, что есть уже готовое решение, не думаю, что я первый кто с таким столкнулся.

Comment: Ну вам уже ответили. Весь путь передается в контроллер и уже там его разбиваете на подкатегории. По другому никак.